# Firebase Firestore retrieve data Synchronously/without callbacks

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore in a separate thread in my Android app, so I don't want to use listeners `OnSuccessListener` and `OnFailureListener` to run in yet another thread. Can I just make my thread wait for the result (and catch any exceptions if needed)?

Currently the code for querying is something like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("someCollection").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {
         // do something on the UI thread with the retrieved data
         }
    });
```

What I'd like to have:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("someCollection").getAndWaitForResult();
//Block the thread and wait for result, no callbacks. 
//getAndWaitForResult() is not a real function, just something to describe my intention.
```

I used to work with Parse Server before, and it was quite trivial there.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you may have to cancel the request you start in `onStop` or `onPause` .

Comment: Not really. I added some code to illustrate.

Comment: You could use `EventListener` and implement it with some custom class, and trigger what you want with `onEvent()`

Comment: EventListener will tringger an asyncronous operation, I am specifically asking if there is any way to avoid that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can synchronously load data, because a `DocumentReference.get()` returns a `Task`.
So you can just wait on that task.

If I do something like:

```
    val task: Task<DocumentSnapshot> = docRef.get()
```

then I can wait for it to complete by doing

```
val snap: DocumentSnapshot = Tasks.await(task)
```

This is useful when piplining other operations together after the get() with continuations which may take a little while:

val task: Task = docRef.get().continueWith(executor, continuation)

Above, I am running a continuation on a separate executor, and I can wait for it all to complete with `Tasks.await(task)`.

See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks

Note: You can't call Tasks.await() on your main thread. The Tasks API specifically checks for this condition and will throw an exception.

There is another way to run synchronously, using transactions.
See [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46634746/firestore-runtransaction-and-offline-work)

Comment: I missed that, thanks. 
Since my answer is not related anymore, I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Your can do something like this on the **main thread**...

```
YourObject yourObject = (YourObject)new RunInBackground().
                          execute("someCollection","someDocument").get()
```

And the **background thread** is...

```
public class RunInBackground extends AsyncTask {

  @Override
  protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

    Task<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshotTask = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().
             collection((String) objects[0]).document((String) objects[1]).get();

    YourObject obj=null;

    try {
        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = Tasks.await(documentSnapshotTask);

        obj = new YourObject();
        obj.setter(documentSnapshot.get("your field"));

    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return obj;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested this yesterday but it didn't halt code execution or make it synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin, add an extension function:

```kotlin
private suspend fun <TResult> Task<TResult>.await(): TResult? {
   return try {
       Tasks.await(this)
   } catch (e: Exception) {
       null
   }
}
```

Now you can do

```kotlin
val snapshot = fireStore.collection(USER_ROOT_PATH).document(documentPath)?.get()?.await()
```