# SignOut is making not possible to save in firestore

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a signup activity for an app and something weird is happening can you help me?

this is the code for signup some on and it works if I comment the signOut function but I need it to signout after saving the data in the FirebaseAuth and the Firestore.

I don't get even the logs.

```
public void registUser() {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword()).addOnCompleteListener(SignUpUserActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                Toast.makeText(SignUpUserActivity.this, "Sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                //FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                user.setId(task.getResult().getUser().getUid());

                user.save();

                mAuth.signOut();
                finish();



            } else {
                String erro = "";
                try {
                    throw task.getException();


                } catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
                    erro = "Digite uma senha mais forte";
                } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                    erro = "Email invalido";
                } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                    erro = "Email Registado";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    erro = "Erro generico";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(SignUpUserActivity.this, erro, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    });
}
```

I think its because it takes to long to save things in the database.
I have no problems with the Auth part.

Thank you.

this is the save function.

```
 public void save(){


    DocumentReference reference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("/Clinicas/" + clinic + "/Profissionais/" + id + "/");
    Map<String, Object> dataToSave = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    dataToSave.put("Name", name);
    dataToSave.put("email", email);
    dataToSave.put("clinic", clinic);
    dataToSave.put("Job", job);
    reference.set(dataToSave).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d("artur", "Saved");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w("artur", "Not Saved",e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why would you sing-in the user and then when everything is complete to sign him out?

Comment: I'm not sign him In, I'm signing him up. after that I need him to go the first activity.

Comment: That's good but why are you using `mAuth.signOut();` inside the `onComplete()` method? What you are doing, basically means, once you have succeeded with the authentication process, sign out. Is this what you want?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47021042/9025311

Comment: Yes, I want it to signUp save the data in the Firestore and the FirebaseAuth and after that signOut and finish the activity. and it works if I don't signOut. 

I also saw the same code but with firebase realtime database and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sovle this, please use the following code:

```
user.setId(task.getResult().getUser().getUid());
userRef.set(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        mAuth.signOut();
    }
});
```

When you sign-out, you need to be sure that your write operation is done and this can only be achieved using `addOnSuccessListener`.

Comment: where do i put the code? sorry a little bit of a novice

Comment: You replace this line of code: `mAuth.signOut();` with my code, does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't let me add the addOnSuccessListener

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I forgot to add the set() call. because you need to set the user object on reference. So `userRef` is the reference where you need to add user's data, right?

Comment: I did it by putting the signOut() inside the save function on the onSuccess.
I'm going to try that tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void save(){


    DocumentReference reference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("/Clinicas/" + clinic + "/Profissionais/" + id + "/");
    Map<String, Object> dataToSave = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    dataToSave.put("Name", name);
    dataToSave.put("email", email);
    dataToSave.put("clinic", clinic);
    dataToSave.put("Job", job);
    reference.set(dataToSave).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d("artur", "Saved");
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mAuth.signOut();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w("artur", "Not Saved",e);
        }
    });




}
```