# Accessing data from an array within another javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access the rate variable from outside the function in which it is defined.  I have declared a global rate variable but it is "undefined" at the point I need to use it. I've minimized the code to keep it as clean as possible.

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var docRef = db.collection("pricing").doc("default");

var rate; //Setting up global variable to store value

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data().base); //This works
        rate = doc.data().base;
        console.log("Rate:", rate); //This works
    });

console.log("Rate:", rate); //rate is "undefined" but rate variable value
//is accessible if typed via the console?
```

Comment: Your `console.log` on the last line gets executed before `get()` is resolved. You should read up on promises and how JavaScript handles asynchronous code to learn more about this behavior.

Comment: Thank you Wex, I will read up on this but any steer as to the code changes I can use to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

`docRef.get()` is asynchronous and returns immediately, before the query is complete.  You use that promise to attach a callback function using `then` that gets invoked some time later.  Meanwhile, your code will continue to execute.  What you are observing is that the console log is running before `rate` gets defined in the callback.

You will have to adjust things so that your code that depends on `rate` being defined must only execute after the callback.  This typically means that you write the code *inside* the callback, or using another callback.

It's strongly advisable to learn how JavaScript promises work, as they are critical to writing effective code.

Comment: Thank you Doug, I will read up on this but any steer as to the code changes I can use to make this work?

Comment: Yes, put the log inside the callback, not outside.

Answer (score 0):

`rate` is being assigned inside *then* block, which is executed when [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), returned from `docRef.get()` will be resolved. So at the moment of calling `console.log`, as of *then* block executes asynchronously, `rate` is not assigned yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's a race condition: `rate` is assigned when the promise returns--after your `console.log`.

You could set your code up to run synchronously; then, the `console.log` will not run until after the data have been returned:

[Firebase Firestore retrieve data Synchronously/without callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896112/firebase-firestore-retrieve-data-synchronously-without-callbacks/47021042#47021042)

Note that this is generally not recommended, as it can negatively affect performance and UX. Pay close attention, and you may notice a short lock-up of the interface. Regardless, per your OP, since you are a "newbie," this may help you here for learning and testing.